# How to stop countdown after zero

Tags: javascript, php, countdown

i try to create a `javascript` to countdown then redirect to another site.

but when it reach zero and page loading, countdown start to count `-1`, `-2`, etc. up to redirect to another page.

Here what I have try:

```
function countdown(remaining) {
    if(remaining === 0)
        window.location = '<?php echo $link_redirect ?>';
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = remaining;
    setTimeout(function(){ countdown(remaining - 1); }, 1000);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adding the condition to only count down when remaining is more than 0

```
function countdown(remaining) {
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = remaining;
    if(remaining > 0) {
        setTimeout(function(){ countdown(remaining - 1); }, 1000);
    } else {
        window.location = '<?php echo $link_redirect ?>';
    }
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your page loading will take time so till that your script will execute continuously. You can write code of counter decrease in else part.

```
function countdown(remaining) {
if(remaining === 0)
window.location = '<?php echo $link_redirect ?>';
else
{
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = remaining;
    setTimeout(function(){ countdown(remaining - 1); }, 1000);
}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function countdown(remaining) {
    if(remaining === 0){
        window.location = '<?php echo $link_redirect ?>';
    } else{
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = remaining;
        setTimeout(function(){ countdown(remaining - 1); }, 1000);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
countdown(20);
function countdown(remaining) {
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = remaining;
  if(remaining === 0) {
    //window.location = '<?php echo $link_redirect ?>';
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "redirect"
  } else {
    setTimeout(function(){ countdown(remaining - 1); }, 1000);
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="countdown">
</div>
```

Comment: Although this answer might be what the OP wants and it could fixes the OP problem, it's always better to explain what you did because just bumping a little snippet with no explanation is a little low quality.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my example it is working perfectly:

```js
$(function(){countdown1($('#countdown1').html());})
function countdown1(remaining) {
console.log('remaining is : ' + remaining);
    if(remaining === 0)
        window.location = '<?php echo $link_redirect ?>';
    $('#countdown1').html(remaining);
    setTimeout(function(){ countdown1(remaining - 1); }, 1000);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="countdown1">10</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on a theme perhaps using anonymous functions

```
<div id='countdown'></div>
<script>
    (function( time, url ){

        /* variable used as a timer */
        var t=NaN;

        (function(){
            /* display current count */
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML=time;

            /* invoke anonymous function every second */
            t=setTimeout( arguments.callee, 1000 );

            /* if the countdown has expired, clear the timer and redirect */
            if( time <= 0 ){
                clearTimeout( t );
                location.href=url;
            }
            /* reduce count */
            time--;
        })();
    /* configure time and url here */
    })( 10, 'http://www.example.com' );
</script>
```